# Maximum Size of Antichains

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $P$ be a finite poset, $m$ be the maximum size of an antichain in $P$, and $C$ be a maximal chain in $P$.

Do we then have for any antichain $A \subseteq P\setminus C : |A|<m$? If not, could you give an example?

Comment: What are your thoughts? Have you tried constructing counterexamples in order to build some intuition?

Comment: There's a 4-element counterexample shaped like the letter N.